# Login to web page using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, httpwebrequest, webclient

I am trying to login to the website below using HttpWebRequest. I am passing in the username and password using the Credentials property but keep getting back the Login page of the website. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong.

https://oyster.tfl.gov.uk/oyster/entry.do (Login Page)

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Url);
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; 
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
request.Method = "POST";
request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5");
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate");
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.Headers.Add("Keep-Alive: 300");
request.Referer = Url;
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)";

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    string tmp = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: (your actions appear to violate the TfL terms and conditions; I would look at that first...)

Answer (score 1):

**note the [Terms and Conditions](http://www.tfl.gov.uk/termsandconditions/default.aspx)**:

> The following are prohibited [...snip...]
>
> Use of any automated system, software
>   or process to extract content and/or
>   data, including trawling, data mining
>   and screen scraping.

`Credentials` is for basic/etc http security - **not** forms-based security.

It would be better to use an API if one exists. HTML forms are meant for humans, not computers. It looks like there is a [beta TfL API here](http://data.london.gov.uk/apibeta).

Answer (score 0):

That page has no HTTP authentication (Basic, Digest, NTLM) on it, so Credentials will do nothing.

You need to construct a POST to `/oyster/security_check` that sends the username and password as content (the data to send will look the same what you would see in the query string if the form were a GET, e.g. `username=myName&password=myPass`. Maintain the cookie from this for subsequent requests.

Comment: (note that this violates the site terms ;p)

Comment: @Marc Well it's using the content found by traversing it that they claim the right to prohibit, rather than logging in, and that might not stand up in a court of law, that I know of there are Supreme Court appeals on such matters pending in the US and in Ireland, while Denmark, ironically the one country to partially ban "deeplinking" (what a stupid decision that was - there's no such think as a "deep link") okayed scraping in at least some uses. Besides, google cache has already scraped a lot of the content you don't need a login for. Anyway, we've answered the technical question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a C# class that you might find quite useful.

It's quite simple to use and has basic functions for downloading a string or byte array. It also scans the login page form for things like authentication tokens that some websites use to prevent programmatic authentication. I have tried it with a number of websites such as Facebook and it seems to work just fine.

[Link Removed]